# Lost Formatting with Public Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, public

I lost some key formatting when making our VisualForce page public, and I'd like to know how to correct this.

I've made the page public and enable public access to the static resources.

**Here is what it should look like:**
[image]

**Here is what it does look like:**
[image]

**As you can see, I have the following issues that I've noticed:**

• Input text fields, picklist, and multi-picklist fields are no longer available - (note: I have given guest users access to create objects I believe, so I'm not sure why these aren't available)

•  My background is visible at the edges, but it looks like it's behind the white background from SalesForce

• Is there any way to get rid of the SalesForce header at the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issues by doing the following:

Fixing the Formatting Overrides from Salesforce CSS:
• Added standardStyleSheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" to the Apex page

Fixing the non-visible fillable fields:
• Setup-> Sites->Clicked on "Intakes" site -> Clicked on "Public Access Settings" -> Scroll down to "Field-Level Security" -> Click "View" next to "Intake" ->Click edit in the next screen and assign "Read Access" to each dropdown value individually manually